# Azure Sentinel - Missing Office 365 logs

Tags: azure, azure-sentinel

I am evaluating Azure Sentinel preview. 
I connected a Office 365 subscription (for which I am the admin) and tested few logins. No matter what I do, I dont see any mailbox logins logs in the Azure sentinel.

What am I missing?

[image: Connector to Office 365]

[image: No logs]

Answer (score 2):

To get sign-ins logs you need to connect AAD sign-in logs, not the Office 365 logs.

So, instead of (or in addition to) connecting to Office 365 logs in Azure Sentinel, also select the Azure Active Directory Box in the Azure Sentinel Data Connectors Screen and connect to Azure Active Directory. This would allow you to receive in Azure Sentinel sign-in logs for any activity that utilizes Azure Active Directory for authentication, including Office 365.

You can find additional instructions on connecting Azure Active Directory logs to Azure Sentinel [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/connect-azure-active-directory).

Screenshot: [Azure Sentinel Data Connectors screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IMA2.png)